# Label on Marker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I've followed some guides but label isn't displayed on my map.
I use Ionic.
This is my code (in map controller):

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var stylesMap = [
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        styles: stylesMap
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmaps-canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        labelContent: "$425K",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        zIndex: 10000,
        icon: "img/marker/tuseiqui.png"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    });
```

And this is the css:

```
.labels {
 color: red;
 background-color: white;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;     
 border: 2px solid black;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Marker is correctly viewed on the map, but it doesn't display its label..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like a sample for the [`MarkerWithLabel`](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html)-library.

You must include the [library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js) and create a `new MarkerWithLabel` instead of a  `new google.maps.Marker`

```js
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
var stylesMap = [{
  featureType: "poi",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
}];
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  styles: stylesMap
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmaps-canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  labelContent: "$425K",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
  labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
  zIndex: 10000
    //,icon: "img/marker/tuseiqui.png"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {});
```

```css
html,
body,
#gmaps-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.labels {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>
<div id="gmaps-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfecly! :)

Comment: Sorry, can I use more label with different width and center it to marker?

Comment: And other problem.. Click on more markers doesn't work.. I add it with this:
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    $scope.setInfoWindow(data[i].id);
                }
            })(marker, i));

Comment: I'm not familiar with ionic/angularjs. Please create a fiddle based on your current implementation and I will take a look.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with angularjs. With your code, the label click works, but the marker click not. I do a fiddle soon.